# How to add dynamic field row in web2py form

Tags: web2py

Is it possible to have multiple fields for one database model in web2py form? Say, I want to add multiple grocery items from same page using dynamic field adding with javascript like this

http://blog.calendarscripts.info/dynamically-adding-input-form-fields-with-jquery/

EDIT: I have two models. 'order' and 'item'. each order has multiple items. I need to add multiple items from each order's page.

```
db.define_table('order',Field('order_number','string'))
db.define_table('item',Field('name','string'),Field('quantity','integer'),Field('order_id','reference order'))
```

I can dynamically add field row using javascript. But unsure how to submit multiple records to same model

Comment: Can you show your data model and explain in more detail exactly what you want? It is not clear whether you want to add multiple records to a single table or whether you have a master/detail model, with multiple child records linked to a single master record.

Comment: Hi @Anthony.. Added more details to question.